# Can't use proxy within selenium vba script

Tags: vba, excel, selenium, web-scraping, selenium-chromedriver

I've written a script in `vba` in combination with `selenium`. The script does it's jobs just fine if I comment out the line I may have wrongly defined for `proxy`.

How can I run my scraper using `proxy`? I searched a lot but could not find a match that could help me solve this.

This is my try:

```
Sub UseProxy()
    Dim driver As New ChromeDriver, post As Object

    With driver
        .setProxy "38.131.10.78:53281"
        .get "https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/web-scraping"
        For Each post In .FindElementsByCss(".question-hyperlink")
            R = R + 1: Cells(R, 1) = post.Text
        Next post
        .Quit
    End With
End Sub
```

If I execute the macro, It throws an error `object doesn't support this method ------`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As follows, from method by [@Ulixestoitaca](https://github.com/florentbr/SeleniumBasic/issues/159):

```
Option Explicit
Private Sub Use_Proxy()
    Dim d As WebDriver, post As Object, R As Long
    Set d = New ChromeDriver
    With d
        .Start
        .Proxy.SetHttpProxy "38.131.10.78:53281" 
        .get "https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/web-scraping"

        For Each post In .FindElementsByCss(".question-hyperlink")
            R = R + 1: Cells(R, 1) = post.Text
        Next post

        .Quit
    End With
End Sub
```